# Stock trading Chol Hamoed

Tags: halacha, business, chol-hamoed, orach-chaim

From what I understand, one is not allowed to do “commerce”, in the sense of having a business open, on chol hamoed (with the exception of it being open for a mitzvah).

Is one allowed to trade, buy and sell stocks on chol hamoed in a non Jewish company that they would be a minority owner of (like Amazon, Disney, Apple etc.) in the same way one is allowed to own stock in non kosher businesses if they have minority holding and don’t have voting rights? Is there a Teshuvah on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work that must be done to avoid loss or damage is permitted on Chol Hamoed (it is called *[davar ha-aved](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/12-12-02/)*). As such some halachic authorities permit selling stock that you are afraid might lose value, while buying stock is forbidden (missing on profit is typically not included in *davar ha-aved*).

R Chaim Jachter [writes](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/chol-hamoed-observance-in-modern-times-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter) this explicitly

> Contemporary examples of Davar Haaved include selling stocks because
> he fears that the stock will soon lose value

Not everyone agrees so be sure to ask your Rav in case this applies to you.